# Which body packs to go for?

Tags: gear

I have a choice between the Sennheiser EK 2000 or the Sony URXP2/4244. Which of the two works better?

Comment: For the price of the Sennheiser packs, you can almost get two of the Sony packs, if that's a consideration.

Comment: @ Dave Matney - are you sure considered that the Sony are sold separately as transmitters/receivers? ;) they're going to be comparable in price once you take into account full transmitter/receiver pair.

Comment: Touche... I just did a quick Google search to see the prices, and that was generally what I found.

Answer (score 1):

LectroSonics.
Always

Comment: Imho, if you have the cash for Lectrosonics, you might as well go for Zaxcom. They have built-in backup recorders, remote gain adjust, tc sync and an encrypted signal.

Answer (score 0):

@Dave Matney and @Shaun Farley - not really the price that bothers me. just want to know which is more reliable and over all works better. have you guys had any experience with them?

Comment: I have no experience with either, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I am very happy with the Sennheisers that we use, and have had no problems with any of the packs we have hired, also all Sennheisers.

Comment: I'll second that. Sennheisers also can go a whole day without having to change the batteries. That's an awesome feature. 